# How can i affect all content within a tag except a specific child tag

Tags: css, css-selectors, combinators

i have the following code example

i am trying to affect all h1 content except the <strong> content

i tried using the child combinator and the :first-child selector and couldnt, thanks in advance

```css
h1 {
  background-color: aqua;
}


/* option 1 */

div h1:not( > strong) {
  background-color: yellow;
}


/* option 2 */

div h1:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <strong>STRONG Line #1, Intended to stay the same aqua</strong><br> Line #2, Intended to be Yellow.
  </h1>
</div>
<span>Line #3, not in the div at all.</span>
```

here is the testing console
[developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/play?id=%2BtruFr4D3mNnbpt1zrIJBvVDuKsNiXZ0FHJmHlVewDDv8FXoC5S6XbBtazV66Xov7FhkeDJFEFgTF0m4)

Answer (score 1):

Your colors seem to be round the wrong way in your CSS. If you swap them it simplifies your selectors. Essentially color the `h1` background and then target the `strong` inside the `h1`.

```css
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div h1 strong {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <strong>STRONG Line #1, Intended to stay to be aqua</strong><br>
    Line #2, Intended to be Yellow.
  </h1>
</div>
<span>Line #3, not in the div at all.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

To explain what is your problem here:

The background-color in fact ***does not affect the `strong` part, specifically, at all***.

It **only appears to do this**, *visually* (!), because by default the `background-color` of `strong` is `transparent`, making the bg color of the surrounding h1 look like it's also the bg color of the strong element.

As soon as your  `strong` element has an opaque bg color applied this becomes clear:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

strong {
  background-color: aqua; /* replaces the default "transparent"! */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <strong>STRONG Line #1, Intended to stay to be aqua</strong><br>
    Line #2, Intended to be Yellow.
  </h1>
</div>
<span>Line #3, not in the div at all.</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you target the `strong` element within the `h1` directly, you can style it to be different than the rest of the content. See the below as an example:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

div h1 strong {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    <strong>STRONG Line #1, Intended to stay the same aqua</strong><br>
    Line #2, Intended to be Yellow.
  </h1>
</div>
<span>Line #3, not in the div at all.</span>
```